# How do I include my assemblies for a Project Template when packaged in a VSIX

Tags: c#

I have a project template that builds a windows forms application. The windows forms application must have a reference to an assembly that I have also built.

When I package the project template in a VSIX (or just build it and put it in the templates folder), the project does not have a reference to the assembly. How can I package the assembly in the VSIX? Ideally I'd like to install it in the GAC but I know this is not possible - is there any way for me to create a folder in the project with a name like 'Dependencies' and include my assembly there? And how can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

OK I have solved this.

The way I do it is create a project I will use as a baseline for the template. Then I include the DLLS in the actual project files, in a Folder named 'Dependencies'. These have their build action set to 'None'. After this, I add references (by path) to the binaries in the Dependencies folder. Now when I export the project as a template everything works fine.